# Debian Prompts to Change Password Before Expiry Date

Tags: debian, passwords

When I try to log into one of my Debian VM's I am asked to change my password:

[image: Prompt to change password]

However, the `/etc/shadow` file contains this line:

```
user:$6$N1MivDoahXzQSd...ZBGwUD40:18153:0:99999:7:::
```

And `getent shadow user` returns the same information:

```
# diff -s <(grep user /etc/shadow) <(getent shadow user)
Files /dev/fd/63 and /dev/fd/62 are identical
```

Which is consistent with the output of `chage -l user`:

```
Last password change                    : Sep 14, 2019
Password expires                    : never
Password inactive                   : never
Account expires                     : never
Minimum number of days between password change      : 0
Maximum number of days between password change      : 99999
Number of days of warning before password expires   : 7
```

`user` is a local user.

Hence, I did not expect this prompt to show up earlier than the 28th of June 2293 (`1970-01-01 + 18153d + 99999d = 2293-06-28`).

What causes this prompt?

Comment: Do you get the same line via `getent shadow user`? Does `chage -l user` show the same interpretation of the values? Is this a fully local account or does it involve a network database?

Comment: I have added all requested information to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something must have gone wrong, when I woke up the host OS from hibernation. The kernel log showed that the VM was warped into the year 2296 (Note the kernels' timestamps):

```
Jul 15 12:30:34 debian kernel: [8734132861.223020] 10:56:00.545787 timesync vgsvcTimeSyncWorker: Radical host time change: 30 513 582 000 000ns (HostNow=1 570 444 031 609 000 000 ns HostLast=1 570 413 518 027 000 000 ns)
Jul 15 12:30:34 debian kernel: [8734132861.223044] 10:56:00.545814 timesync vgsvcTimeSyncWorker: Radical guest time change: 8 734 120 316 289 565 000ns (GuestNow=-8 142 210 239 462 377 616 ns GuestLast=1 570 413 517 957 609 000 ns fSetTimeLastLoop=false)
```

After a restart everything was back to normal.